# Кусок блока не там в Opera

Tags: opera, html, css

Если зайти на [мой сайт](http://inferusvv.ru/) с помощью Opera, то в футере можно заметить не приятную вещь. Там в блоке "Я здесь" при переносе слова на новую строку кусок остается на старой. nowrap стоит для ссылок. Как избавиться от этого бага?

Comment: Не уверен, но попробуйте для этих ссылок поставить **display: inline-block;**

Comment: @Deonis А вы знаете, работает. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
border-radius: 5px;
color: #FFFFFF;
float: left;
margin: 0px 3px 3px;
opacity: 0.8;
padding: 3px 6px;
text-decoration: none;
white-space: nowrap;
```